# Google appengine memcache scope

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am introducing memcache in a Google app engine app and I need to know if any memcache instance is local to the current user (like a session) or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memcache instance is global and not tight to the `User` instance.

You add values to memcache by key, so you can implement `User` bound memcache on your own, by using user key + some additional info as key to memcache value.

```
memcacheService.put(userKey + "userBalance", userBalance);
```

This will cache `userBalance` per user.

Comment: In this case i think i will exploit the namespace optional parameter

Comment: Of course you can. I haven't used it yet, but sound reasonable for such scenario.

Comment: `namespace` is definitely the right mechanism for such "multi-tenancy" scenarios (for memcache just as for the datastore).